# lightbox window issue in safari and chrome

Tags: jquery, height, lightbox

I have a problem in chrome and safari using the simple lightbox example in the book jquery novice to ninja

[image]

```
$('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden'); // hide scrollbars!
    $('<div id="overlay"></div>')
      .css('top', $(document).scrollTop())
      .css('opacity', '0')
      .animate({'opacity': '0.5'}, 'slow')
      .appendTo('body');
```

The problem is if the page is longer than the window I can scroll and see a distinct line between the overlay and the where the jquery calculated to the height of the window,

in firefox, I can't scroll. So this is not really a problem; Colorbox or another is not an option as I need to do too much customisation to the loightbox.

Comment: take a look at fancybox.

Comment: 'Colorbox or another is not an option'

Comment: I was more in suggesting how to how they fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

`position: fixed` for the overlay sorts this problem nicely!